# How to send more than one parameter with StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to send an array and a key to another screen using `StackNavigator`, but it tells me that the program does not see the `getNoteArray()` function.

```
getNoteArray(){
    return this.state.noteArray;
}

editMethod(key){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('EditNote' , {noteArray: this.getNoteArray(), key});
}
```

Here is the `EditNote` screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
TextInput,
TouchableOpacity,
AsyncStorage,
    } from 'react-native';

import Note from './Note.js';

export default class EditNote extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Edit',
    };


    constructor(props){
         super(props);
        this.state = {
            noteArray: [],
            noteText: '',
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({noteArray: this.props.navigation.state.params.noteArray})
        alert(this.state.noteArray);
    }


    render() {
        const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.noteBody}>
                    <TextInput 
                        multiline = {true}
                        numberOfLines = {1000000}
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        placeholderTextColor='grey'
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                    </TextInput>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
},
noteBody:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderTopColor: '#000',
    marginBottom: 100,
},
textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color: '#000',
    padding: 20,
    borderTopWidth:2,
    borderTopColor: '#ededed',
},
addButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 11,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
    height: 60,
    elevation: 8
},
addButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 24,
},

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens
The syntax is

```
navigation.navigate({routeName, params, action, key}) 
  OR 
navigation.navigate(routeName, params, action)
```

So it can be

```
navigate('EditNote' , { notesArray: getNoteArray(), key} ); 
   OR


navigate({ 
     routeName: 'EditNote' , 
     params: { 
       notesArray: getNoteArray(),
      key
     }
   });
```

Comment: Indeed. But when I navigate to the screen, it doesn't see the `getNoteArray()` function

Comment: Could be another problem. Do you want to add a new question for that or add that code as well ?

Comment: I think I will edit this code. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: There. I think that should cover it.

Comment: I also tried in stead of `getNoteArray()` to use `this.state.noteArray` but it shows me an empty alert window.

Comment: ok so , The update might come in `componentDidUpdate`. You dont need to set state , instead use it directly.  ` this.props.navigation.state.params.noteArray`

Comment: I did not used `componentDidUpdate` tho. What change will that bring if I use it in stead of `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Those are component life cycle methods. You don't need internal state for this particular use case since the data is coming from the parent NavigationContainer which sets it properly in the props. You will need to handle null/undefined condition in your render method

Comment: I am not sure that I followed you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
editMethod(key){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('EditNote',{ params1:'hello',params2:'hi'});
}
```